# Java Sorted Set of Maps converted to an array

Tags: java, indexing, treemap, sortedset, toarray

I have these two data structures:

```
public TreeMap<String, Integer> tableFrequency;                  

public SortedSet<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> sortedTable;
```

sortedTable holds the same information as tableFrequency but it is sorted descendingly by the Integer value.

How can I convert sortedTable into an Array consisting of pairs of strings and integers, such that the Array is indexed to keep the same order as the sortedTable? For example to be more clear my array at index 0 would contain the largest value in sortedTable and my array at index[sortedTable.size() - 1] would contain the smallest value in sortedTable.

Comment: This is the kind of thing you can teach yourself via Google and JavaDoc.  Please do some research before posting so we can limit questions to ones that haven't already been answered better elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Map.Entry<String, Integer> sortedArray[] = new Map.Entry<String, Integer>[sortedTable.size()];
sortedArray = sortedTable.toArray(sortedArray);
```

Comment: is Map.Entry<> kind of like a C++ pair<>?

Comment: Yes, actually just like `std::map::value_type` since it's got the two generic parameters from the enclosing `Map`.